# Cant find variable error r1 string

Tags: java

My error is 'can't find variable r1'  Here is [my code](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1LMCDrpoFHeHn-ba1-PIgn_hTB_e4TYF86F4ln7gx49M/edit?usp=sharing)

```
public class lottoticket { 
    public static void main(String[]args){
    int win1 = 1 + (int)(Math.random() * 50);
    int win2 = 1 + (int)(Math.random() * 50);
    int win3 = 1 + (int)(Math.random() * 50);
    ...

    if (t1 == win1){
       String r1 = "winner";
    }
    ...
    System.out.println(t1,"\t",r1);  // <<< ERROR HERE
    ...
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to visit the [help] and read [ask].  Please do not post links to your code, make a minimal example that demonstrates the problem and include the code in your post along with a clear explanation of what you don't understand.

Comment: What part of the error don't you understand?

Comment: i dont unerstand what  it means

Comment: I have edited your question to include the relevant code.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is this:

```
if (t1 == win1){
   String r1 = "winner";
}
```

The variable `r1` exists ONLY within the braces around its declaration.  When you refer to it later it is not visible or accessible (it actually no longer exists).  You should declare it at the top level, thus:

```
String r1;
if (t1 == win1){
   r1 = "winner";
}
```